# Javascript: how do I take my users input data and turn it into an object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a to-do list that I want I can receive user input on via html text boxes. The information is currently printed under these text boxes in an un-ordered list form after a button is clicked.

Its not perfect, that said I skipped a step, I want to take the strings the user inputs with button click and add them first to this function.

```
function task(task_text, date, time)
```

The purpose of this of course is to trade the objects properties throughout the code later.

So, how would I go about taking the information in the text boxes and submit it to the above function on click of the button?

The Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brendanjackson/j501hc1k/1/

Answer (score 1):

### Getting the input onclick

To get this input into the function you must listen for the onclick event.

```
var input_text = document.getElementById('input_text').value;
var input_date = document.getElementById('input_date').value;
var input_time = document.getElementById('input_time').value;
```

`onclick="task(input_text, input_date, input_time);"`

---

*how do I take my users input data and turn it into an object?*

---

When your function is called, you can then create an object from the data passed in, like so:

```
var inputs = [];
function task(task_text, date, time) {
    input.push({
        task_text: task_text,
        date: date,
        time: time
    });
}
```

or if you are only planning to accept one input, you could just do this:

```
var obj = {};
function task(task_text, date, time) {
    obj.task_text: task_text,
    obj.date: date,
    obj.time: time
}
```

Comment: Thats cool and something I think I will want to do but, how do I take the users data on button click and pass it to the function?

Comment: Cool I was sure it was possible I just wasn't sure where to start looking thank you, I'll look into it.

Comment: you had it right with the multiple inputs (array) setup

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/3rh4u7qu/1/

I think this is what you're after:

```
function task(text, date, time) {
    this.text = text;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

function buttonClicked() {
    var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
    var input_text = document.getElementById('input_text').value  ;
    var input_date = document.getElementById('input_date').value  ;
    var input_time = document.getElementById('input_time').value  ;
    var item = new task(input_text, input_date, input_time);
        myText.innerHTML += "<li>"+item.text+" "+item.date+" "+item.time+"</li>";
}
```

Also, added a slightly more interesting use of your task object here which might be useful from a learning perspective: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/3rh4u7qu/2/

Comment: This is a far better answer than the one selected.